# Bug with smooth style and \closedcycle in PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Could you please confirm the bug?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0,ymin=0]
\addplot[fill,opacity=0.5,cyan,domain=0:5,smooth] % smooth breaks \closedcycle
  {1/x} \closedcycle;
\draw[-latex] (axis cs:3,2) node[label=above:Oops!] {} --
  (axis cs:4.9,0.15) node[circle,draw=red,dashed,inner sep=5pt] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Related: [Pgfplots \closedcycle introduces unwanted slope](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44756/pgfplots-closedcycle-introduces-unwanted-slope)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, looks like a bug. You might want to file a [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/).

You can get a correct smooth plot by using `-- (current plot end|-{rel axis cs:1,0}) \closedcycle` instead of just `\closedcycle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0, xmax=6, ymin=0, axis on top]
\addplot[fill,opacity=0.5,cyan,domain=0.2:5,smooth]
  {1/x} -- (current plot end|-{rel axis cs:1,0}) \closedcycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Strangely enough, I can't find the button to report bugs on that link.

Comment: @juliohm: You're right, it seems like the bug reporting has been disabled.

Comment: Sourceforge has recently made a major version upgrade of their software... perhaps that is the cause?