# How to add confidence regions around a graph, from a table

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw confidence regions above and below my graph, a little like below:

[image]

(which is from https://towardsdatascience.com/recreating-netflixs-quantile-bootstrapping-in-r-a4739a69adb6 )

I'm not quite clear how to do this in pgfplots?

Let's say some minimum code to get things started:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
        X   Y       CI95
        1   1.50    0.39
        2   1.05    0.21
        3   0.50    0.14
        4   0.20    0.05
        5   0.35    0.35
    \end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
]
\addplot [] table [x=X, y=Y]{data.txt};
\addplot [] table [x=X, y=CI95]{data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(these numbers don't match the graph depicted from the blog post, but concept is similar, i.e. there are `y`-values, and `ci 95%` values)

Edit: came across https://pgfplots.net/error-intervals/  Maybe useful?

[image]

And this also looks relevant: [Pgfplots \closedcycle introduces unwanted slope](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44756/pgfplots-closedcycle-introduces-unwanted-slope/44767#44767)

[image]

Comment: note: the linked question as a 'duplicate' is not really a duplicate, since that question asked about how to remove the duplicate plots from the legends. and the answers use stacked plots, and closedloop, which are in my opinion more complicated to use. I cannot add a new answer there about using y expr and fill between, since that wouldnt answer the question of how to remove the surplus plots from the legend (ie using `forget plot`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out :)

Basically, we use `y expr` to draw confidence limits above and below the line. We use the new `fillbetween` package to fill the area between these lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
        X   Y       CI95
        1   1.50    0.39
        2   1.05    0.21
        3   0.50    0.14
        4   0.20    0.05
        5   0.35    0.35
    \end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
]
\addplot [name path=lower, fill=none, draw=none] table [
    x=X, y expr=\thisrow{Y} - \thisrow{CI95}]{data.txt};
\addplot [name path=upper, fill=none, draw=none] table [
    x=X, y expr=\thisrow{Y} + \thisrow{CI95}]{data.txt};
\addplot[green!40] fill between[of=lower and upper];
\addplot [] table [x=X, y=Y]{data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that it's also possible to make the confidence region transparent, using e.g. `fill opacity=0.2`. This lets you have multiple overlapping lines and C.I. regions, and the overlapping C.I. regions are slightly darker than the non-overlapped bits.